# Toolbar cannot be customized as expected in android

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

I'm learning Material Design from video tutorial provided by slidenerd.In that they put one next icon on toolbar,everything is working in that tutorial but when i'm implemented it the icon is not appearing.

Here,i'm attaching my files please have a look and help me out at my learning stage.Please!!!

MainActivity.java

```
package materialtest.example.ritzipsy.mytoolbar5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Enable the Up button
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.id_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Setting menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.id_navigate) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Next menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="materialtest.example.ritzipsy.mytoolbar5.MainActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never">></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_navigate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_next_arrow"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Next"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.co0m/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Got Output as

[image]

Expected output to be

[image]

Comment: If you give a link to the tutorial that would help I guess

Comment: you can get the video here   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAZv1fP-5TM&index=5&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Answer (score 1):

Just change your menu xml as below. The problem is with this line
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/tools"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_navigate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_next_arrow"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Next"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```